# Automated Download Timer in Java

Tags: java, timer

I am working on a download timer programmed in Java. My goal is to automatically start the timer when the download begins and stop it as it stops. I have a basic timer that counts seconds as the program starts, but I am having problems automating it. I have researched java.io, but I'm not sure if this is what I need.

This is my code so far:

```
package sciencePackage;

public class Timer extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        try {

            for (int i = 1;i < 61; i++)  {

                this.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("System is still running -- " + i );
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Java has 2 built-in `Timer` classes: `java.util.Timer` and `javax.swing.Timer`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `Timer` class seems excessive for the use that you propose, not to mention that there is already a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class built into Java.  However, timers are best used for scheduling actions, not for observing how long they take.

Also, in the code you posted, you have `super.run()` finish before you even start timing.  At that point, there is nothing left for your timer to wait for, unless your download is happening on a different thread that you haven't told us about.

Instead, you could probably do something much simpler, like this:

```
public void run() {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    super.run(); 
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Download Time: " + (end - start) / 1.0e9 + " seconds");
}
```

Comment: I knew this, however I was looking to automate the start/stop time, not the total time. Sorry if this was not clear.